# select rows which has latest date without repetition from two joined table?

Tags: mysql

I have table A and B.

Table A has data like

```
|  id  |    status    | made at | ... |
|  1   |     new      |14-04-14 | ... |
|  2   |    fixed     |14-08-12 | ... |
|  3   |    fixed     |14-03-15 | ... |
| ...  |     ...      |  ..     | ... |
```

and in Table B,

```
|  id  |   A_id   |    changes   |changed at| ... |
|  1   |    1     |     new      | 14-04-14 | ... |
|  2   |    2     |     new      | 14-08-12 | ... |
|  3   |    2     |     fixed    | 14-08-28 | ... |
|  4   |    3     |     new      | 14-03-15 | ... |
|  5   |    3     |    fixed     | 14-05-11 | ... |
|  6   |    3     |    fixed     | 14-05-14 | ... |
|  ..  |   ..     |      ..      |   ..     | ... |
```

What I want as the result is to pick what has fixed status in table A and fixed changes in table B, with `no repetition`.

If it has same `changes` like 5 and 6 in B, I will pick only changed at latest data.

So the result will look like...

```
|  id  |  A_id   |  made at  |  status  |  changes  |  changed at |  ...  |
|  2   |   2     | 14-08-12  |  fixed   |   fixed   |  14-08-28   |  ...  |
|  3   |   3     | 14-03-15  |  fixed   |   fixed   |  14-05-14   |  ...  |
```

I tried `select * from A, B where (A.status='fixed') and (A.id=B.A_id) and (B.changes='fixed')` but still have repetition result in changes.

How can I make query right?

Comment: Your dates are DATES, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Query

```
  SELECT tab.* FROM(SELECT A.*,B.A_id,B.chnages,B.changed at 
 FROM  A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id=B.A_id
 WHERE A.status='fixed' AND B.changes ='fixed' 
 ORDER BY B.changes_at DESC ) as tab GROUP BY tab.id
```

Comment: I tried this. Repetition result disappeared but changed_at data was not latest one, but the oldest one.

Comment: This relies on an undocumented hack (unless you count the comments section of the relevant page of the manual- I don't!)

Answer (score 0):

I think the sample output you've shared is not correct, the id column should have values `3` and `6` instead of `2` and `3`. Anyway try this

```
SELECT b3.id, a.id AS 'A_id', a.made_at AS 'made at', a.status, b3.changes, b3.changed_at AS 'changed at'
FROM
    a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT b1.id, b1.A_id, b1.changes, b1.changed_at FROM b AS b1 
        INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT A_id, MAX(changed_at) AS changed_at FROM b WHERE changes='fixed' GROUP BY 1) AS b2 ON b1.A_id=b2.A_id AND b1.changed_at=b2.changed_at
    ) b3 ON a.id=b3.A_id
WHERE
    a.status = 'fixed'
```

Comment: what is b1? and what do you mean by 'tableA AS a'? didn't you mean a and b as the table names?

Comment: @W.Cointreau, i thought A and B are aliases you are using for your tables, if A and B are your actual table names then i've changed the query. b1, b2 and b3 are aliases (short names) given to table b to distinguish between multiple usages

Comment: thank you for your answer. I didn't use aliases in my question (actually I didn't know what the alias is, I'm a newbie of mysql :'( ) and it was real table name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    b.A_id,
    a.status,
    a.made_at,
    b.changes,
    b.changed_at
FROM 
    A a
INNER JOIN
    B b ON b.A_id = a.id
WHERE
    a.status = 'fixed'      
    AND
    b.changes = 'fixed'
    AND 
    b.changed_at = (select 
                          MAX(b1.changed_at)
                        from 
                          b b1 
                        where 
                          b1.changes = b.changes 
                          and b1.A_id = b.A_id
                        )
```